# No overload for 'button3_click' matches delegate system.eventhandler

Tags: c#

I am quite new to C# coding and I am trying to create a 'cancel' button. I get the error message above. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!
My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(button3_Click);
        }
        public void button3_Click(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is a little confusing. Actually your code should compile fine, since the `Form.FormClosing` event expects a method with exact the signature your `button3_Click` has.

But all this does not seem to be what you actually intended. I assume you wanted to add a click handler to your button:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.button3.Click += button3_Click;
}
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
    this.Close();
}
```

The `Click` event is raised (as the name suggests) when a user clicks the button.

The `FormClosing` is raised when the `Form` is about to close. You can use it (for example) to ask the user for a confirmation:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.button3.Click += button3_Click;
    this.FormClosing += Form1_FormClosing;
}
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
    this.Close();
}
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = MessageBox.Show(this, "Do you really want to quit?", 
            "Quit?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) != DialogResult.Yes;
}
```

With the use of the `FormClosingEventArgs.Cancel` property you can tell the `Form` **not** to close.

Comment: Thanks alot it works fine now using your tips. This function does not cancel a loop, right? Do I have to use interrupt in that case? What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this also works, but it only hide the form. It doesn't really quit running.